# Unable to amplify push when function created

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Using the aws-amplify cli v4.17.1, I don't seem to be able to push my changes through using the 'amplify push' command when a function is included in the amplify project.

E.g. I have created a simple hello world function using the amplify add function command.  Then built the function using the amplify build function command.

Finally, when running amplify push - i receive the following error.

```
× An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Only one CloudFormation template is allowed in the resource directory
An error occurred during the push operation: Only one CloudFormation template is allowed in the resource directory
```

Has anyone else encountered this previously?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, is there any way to fix it

Comment: The issue for me was resolved by upgrading to the latest version of the aws-amplify cli. Which version are you currently on?

Comment: I am also on 4.17.2

Comment: You may need to remove any existing functions first, then recreate them for the changes to take effect. If you look in the amplify functions folder, you will see whether or not it has a cloud formation template inside of the target function. If there is no template present, the. Recreate the function and the push command should then work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved by upgrading to amplify CLI version 4.17.2